# Is it possible to have custom seekbar for YoutubePlayerView

Tags: youtube, seekbar, android-youtube-api

My app uses youtube android sdk to play videos within an activity. And default seekbar matches that of youtube app.

**Is it possible to have a custom seek bar - something like below.**

[sorry - this is my first post and I cant post images]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/twldkm1v42adjyu/blue.png?dl=0

Below is YoutubePlayerView init code in OnCreate()

```
    youtubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youtubePlayerView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
```

Reference of YoutubePlayerView is here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView

One of the constructors takes AttributeSet in its argument (below) - will that be useful ? If not how to go about this - please help.

```
    YouTubePlayerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot style the `YouTubePlayerView`, you can only pick one between the following styles: `DEFAULT`, `CHROMELESS`, `MINIMAL` ([doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle)).

You cannot even place views over the view, otherwise playback will stop.

What you can do is setting the `CHROMELESS` style to the player and manually place a Seekbar **under** the player view. With that, you will then send seek events to the player.

Comment: Thank you - Good idea. Will give it a try